# Nuget Update is not working propelry

Tags: package, nuget, nuget-package, nuget-package-restore, packages.config

I want to `update` the Nuget packages used in the solution file and currently, I am using the following command to update the Nuget packages.

```
NuGet restore <projectPath> [options]
```

Reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/tools/nuget-exe-cli-reference#restore

> **If no solution file, packages.config, or project.json is found, NuGet gives an error.**
>
> Reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/tools/nuget-exe-cli-reference#remarks

But the problem is I am using the `packages.ProjectName.Config` instead of `packages.config` file.So the NuGet update is not properly working.

> Note: Similarly if the folder contains **multiple project and solution files** the NuGet update is not working.

Please suggest how to overcome this issue?

> Edit:
> Initially I thought the **packages.[projectname].config** usage in my source is the reason for NuGet packages restoring but later I found that NuGet packages are not even properly restored with packages.config files.

I have more than solution and project file in my source, After deleting the other projects, The NuGet restore is working properly in my source.

> Is having **more than one solution file is the reason for Nuget not updating**? Anyone faced the problems , Any help to overcome this issue will be useful.

Comment: Sounds like a bug if this is not working. I would file a bug report at http://github.com/nuget/home/issues

Comment: @MattWard Thanks , Please share the link , if the bug is reported.

Comment: I meant for you to file the bug :)

Answer (score 5):

Nuget restore requires a Visual Studio solution file, a `packages.config` file or a `project.json` file.

See the [remarks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/tools/nuget-exe-cli-reference#remarks) for it's beavior.

Comment: Yes, I have mentioned the same in the Question itself

Comment: is it possible to achieve the same when we changed the project name

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you can't specify an arbitrary name but you should be able to accommodate your scenario as of NuGet 2.8. The project names just need to match the filenames - I don't imagine spaces are allowed.

[NuGet release notes;](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/release-notes/nuget-2.8)

> Individual packages.config Files for Different Platforms
>   When developing applications for multiple target platforms, it is common to have different project files for each of the respective build environments. It is also common to consume different NuGet packages in different project files, as packages have varying levels of support for different platforms. NuGet 2.8 provides improved support for this scenario by creating different packages.config files for different platform-specific project files.

[image: ReactiveUI packages.config files]

Looks like ReactiveUI do this, so worth checking their repo;

[ReactiveUI Github](https://github.com/reactiveui/ReactiveUI/tree/develop/src/ReactiveUI)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, Currently I am unable to check this solution and I will check and update you.